# ClassNotFoundException of com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, when using servlets

Tags: servlets, web-applications, jdbc, classnotfoundexception

this wierd problem is very interrupting me for a long time. I have a class name `Connector` inside dynamic web application in eclipse, with these code:

```
public class Connector {

    private static final String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";

    private Connection con;

    public Connector(String userName, String password) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, userName, password);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.print("Unidentified exception has acurred!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

when I'm using it from different Class in the same package, named portal, it works fine, but when I'm trying to use it from servlet in package `servlets`, named `LoginHandle.java`, I get ClassNotFoundException. 
The Class is in the build path of all classes, and I checked it by trying to import it from the servlet, but when I create new instance, it is not being recognized. I tried to move the servlet to the package of the connector, and vise versa, and it didn't affect. Here is the servlet's code:

```
    package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import portal.Connector;
import portal.UserTableAnalyzer;


@WebServlet("/LoginHandle")
public class LoginHandle extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public LoginHandle() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String referer = request.getHeader("Referer");
        String pageName = referer.substring(referer.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        if(pageName.equals("Login.jsp"))
        {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            Connector c = new Connector("root", "16180339887");

            c.executeUpdate("USE Main");
            String id = request.getParameter("id"), password = request.getParameter("password");
            String query = "SELECT FROM Users WHERE id ='" + id + "' AND password = '" + password + "'";
            String[][] result = c.executeQuery(query);

            UserTableAnalyzer uta = new UserTableAnalyzer(result);
            if(result.length > 0)
            {
                session.setAttribute("userID", uta.getID(0));
                session.setAttribute("role", uta.getRole(0));
                response.sendRedirect("Main.jsp");
            }
            else
            {
                request.setAttribute("wrongDetails", new Boolean(true));
                response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp");
            }
        }
        else
            response.getWriter().print(pageName);
    }

}
```

sorry if my english is bad, or if details are missing

Answer (score 0):

Your driver is not in the server classpath, build path has nothing to do with that.
You didn't write which application server are you using. You also should use DataSource in servlets, rather than DriverManager. [Here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) is sample configuration for Tomcat.

UPDATE

For Tomcat 7 you need to do the following:

Put mysql jar in the `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`
Configure `Datasource` in context

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                       maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
                       username="user" password="pass" 
                       driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                       url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName"/>
```

Use Datasource in servlet (pseudo code)

```
@WebServlet("/LoginHandle")
public class LoginHandle extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Resource(lookup="jdbc/testDB")
    private DataSource ds;

    ...

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

   Connection c = ds.getConnection();
   ...
```

Comment: ok, you're right, The server is apache tomcat 7. I don't really understand what classpath is, and how should I configure it, or set it, or whatever. I'll check about the DataSource, but if I use a class in JSP file, it should work if servlet because the server translate JSP to servlet, I think...

Comment: ok, I used DataSource in the Connector class, and it still didn't work, and then I added the jar to $CATALINA_HOME/lib, and I works fine, thank you very much! anyway, I didn't had to add things to the servlet class, because the problem was the missing jar